# SOCAT command for UDP relay using single port

Tags: udp, ip-forwarding, socat

I am using SOCAT linux command for relaying udp packets. Currently I am simulating using VMware.

I used `sudo socat -T 10 UDP4-LISTEN:132,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:192.168.11.130:130,bind=192.168.11.131:133` command that listens on port 132 and forward udp traffic through forking a child process to 192.168.11.130:130 using 133 port (192.168.11.131 is the server address) and it is bi-directional. So if client1:c1 start sending udp packets to 192.168.11.131:132, it will forward the traffic to 192.168.11.130:130 and vice-versa

Now, is it possible that I just configure server (192.168.11.131) 's 131 port which will listen to any UDP connection/packets like from client1:c1, client2:c2, client3:c3 etc and forward the traffic to all incoming addresses without the sender using "SOCAT" command? or atleast is this possible with 2 client and a single port?